# Redirect page at certain time

Tags: php, html, time, redirect

The html/php page needs to redirect to another html/php page, which should be kept open for a certain time interval. Then, it needs to revert itself to the original.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL='TV_moem_ruki.php'" />
```

redirects right after the page is loaded.

I've tried combining this

```
header( "Location: TV_moem_ruki.php") ;
```

into the script below, which refreshes the page at certain point in time, but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
refreshAt(13,10,0); //Will refresh the page at 11:05am
</script>
<script>
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if(now.getHours() > hours ||
       (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
header( "Location: TV_moem_ruki.php") ; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: not needed for header() php function into javascript. just use `window.location.href="TV_moem_ruki.php";` in setTimeout function

Comment: Thanks. This one worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it several ways, by pasting this code in the second page (the one that only stays open for few seconds):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="{numberOfSeconds}; url='TV_moem_ruki.php'" />
```

or with javascript

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = 'TV_moem_ruki.php'
}, numberOfSeconds * 1000)
```

This assumes that `TV_moem_ruki.php` is the first page, the one that you need to return to.